# How can I efficiently work with more than 100 items on spotipy in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, spotipy

I'm making a public playlist with all the songs from my Liked Songs.
I update it  every once in a while, but to make it more efficient I'm modifying the code so that it only adds the songs that haven't been added yet.
To do this i create a list with the tracks that are already in the playlist. But since you can only work with 100 songs per iteration, it causes me problems because the lengths of the playlist and my liked songs are not equal.

With this next code it only compares with the last 100 songs i have liked. After that, even if the song is already added to the playlist it marks it as if it hasn't

```
biblio = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
lista = sp.playlist_items(playlist_id, fields=None, limit=100, offset=0, market=None, additional_types=('track', 'episode'))

urisb=[]
uris=[]

#uris de playlist
for idx in range(0,len(lista['items']),100):
    for i in lista['items'][idx:idx+100]:
        uris.append(i['track']['uri'])

#uris de likes
def show_tracks():
    for idx in range(0,len(biblio['items']),100):
        for i in biblio['items'][idx:idx+100]:
            urisb=i['track']['uri']
            if urisb in uris:
                print("{}     {}-{}".format(True, i['track']['name'],i['track']['artists'][0]['name']))
            else:
                print("{}     {}-{}".format(False, i['track']['name'], i['track']['artists'][0]['name']))
                #sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id, urisb)
            
show_tracks()
while biblio['next']:
    biblio = sp.next(biblio)
    show_tracks()
```